# $f(z+1)-f(z)$ is a polynomial map, then $f(z)$ is a polynomial map

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

Let $f: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be a map of sets, if the map $f(z+1)-f(z)$ can be written as some polynomial of $z$ with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients, then $f(z)$ can be also written as a polynomial of $z$ with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients.

How to prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure this is true. Take $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}z(z-1)$, and it maps $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ as at least one of $z, z-1$ is even. Then, $f(z+1)-f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+1)z-\frac{1}{2}z(z-1)=z$, i.e. $f(z+1)-f(z)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. However, $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}z^2-\frac{1}{2}z$ is *not* a polynomial with integer coefficients. OTOH, the statement holds if you look at maps $\mathbb Q$ to itself, and polynomials with *rational* (rather than *integer*) coefficients.

Comment: Suppose $f(z)=\sin(2\pi z)$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop  Your example is wonderful, I have edited my question to $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients.

Comment: @lulu f(z) is always $0$ in your example.

Comment: Ah, true.  I thought you were taking rational arguments, but you restricted things to integers.

Comment: I need $f$ to be a map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, this is a question related to Hilbert polynomial of schemes.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of differences of polynomial interpolation? This seems almost immediate with that.

Comment: @CalvinLin. I am not familiar with this, but I will learn this if this method can solve my question. Could you please write an answer with your method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The statement is true even for $ f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} $, which should make sense because we could multiply by the LCM of the denominator.)

Set up the difference table where $ D_0 (z) = f(z) $ and $ D_{i+1} (z) = D_{i} (z+1) - D_{i} (z)$ for $ i \geq 0$.
We are given that $D_i(z)$ are rational for $i\geq 1$.

Claim: $$ f(x) = f(1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{ D_i (1) }{i!} \times f_i (x),$$ where $f_i(x) = (x-1) \times (x-2) \times \ldots \times (x-i)$ are polynomials.

Proof: Refer to [Method of Differences for polynomial interpolation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences/).

Hence, $ f(x)$ is indeed a rational polynomial.

---

As an alternative but equivalent interpretation,

(Fill in the gaps, if any. If you're stuck, show your work and explain what you have tried.)

Define $ f_i (x) = (x-1) (x-2) \ldots (x-i)$ for $ i \geq 1$, which is a polynomial of degree $i$.
Observe that $f_{i+1} (x+1) - f_{i+1} (x) = i f_{i} (x)$ for $ i \geq 1$.
Observe that $ f_i (1) = 0 $ for $ i \geq 1$.

Claim: There exists a representation
$$f(x+1) - f(x) = \sum a_i f_i (x),$$
where $a_i$ are rational numbers.

Sketch of Proof: Work from the highest degree on the LHS downwards, to obtain such a representation.
Note: The RHS are polynomials of degree $i$ which are linearly independent, so the representation is unique.

Corollary: $f(x+1) - f(x) = \sum a_i f_i (x) = \sum \frac{a_i}{i} \left[ f_i (x+1) - f_i (x) \right]$, so we can obtain the representation $ f(x) = \left[ \sum \frac{a_i}{i} f_i (x) \right] + C$, for some constant $C$.
Substituting $ x = 1$, we get $ C = f(1)$.
This gives us our rational polynomial representation.

Comment: $f(z+1)-f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, hence $f(k+1)-f(k) =f(2)-f(1)  + \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{ D_i (1) }{i!} \times [f(k+1)-f(k)]_i (n)$, but how to derive the formula of $f$?

Comment: @Sate What is $g(z)$? I did not use that anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, all make sense with your equivalent interpretation.